# How to import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts without getting StaticInjection error?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I am trying to move away from old angular way of making http calls . I am migrating from angular 4 to 5 .
In my `app.module.ts` , I have made the necessary changes as below :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
...................................................

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    .................
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    .......................
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But when I delete the HTTP module references and import the HTTPClient Module references , I get the errors down  below :

```
   StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
   Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!


Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http! Error: StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
   at _NullInjector.prototype.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:99248:13)
   at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:108909:5)
  

  NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!
   at _NullInjector.prototype.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:99248:13)
   at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:99536:9)
   at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:99478:9)
   at StaticInjector.prototype.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:99349:13)
   at _createProviderInstance$1 (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:108920:13)",
      Symbol(observable)_h.ole4xhx75kj: undefined,
      Symbol(rxSubscriber)_g.ole4xhx75kj: undefined
   }
```

I am also using rxjs version  :  ^5.5.2
I am working with below angular versions :

```
devDependencies:
"@angular/cli": "1.4.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
------------------------------------------
dependencies:
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
```

Can someone please advise me as to where I am going wrong ?

**EDIT:** Throughout the application all the instances of `http` have been changed to `httpClient`in all the applicable ts files. Yet , once the `HTTP Module` is deleted from `app.module.ts` and is replaced by `HTTPClient Module`, then we see the issues depicted in the question up above . Currently the application is loading up when both the legacy HTTP Module and HTTPClient Module are present . If any one of them is removed, I start getting errors .

Comment: you need to inject `HttpClient`, not `Http`

Comment: @MarkusDresch  There is no `Http`  throughout the application . It has been remediated into `HttpClient` throughout all the service classes. Yet the same issue , I am seeing through out .

Comment: Does your httpService looks like this: `import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';` and you also have this: `constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }`

Comment: @angularQuestions  Yes Sir. That's exactly how all my service ts files look like . Things just do not work , when I remove the `http Module` from `app.module.ts` . Right now, I can see that the app works if I have both the `HTPModule` and `HTTPCilent Module` in `app.module.ts`. I am not understanding why that is so .

Comment: Ok thats strange - normally this should work - seems like something went wrong during the update - please check the steps for updating from version 4 to 5, maybe you missed something: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=4.0-5.0
You can also check this demo for the usage of HttpClient with Version 5 but according to your description you already using it that way: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-http-example?file=polyfills.ts

Comment: @angularQuestions Appreciate you trying to help me out. I have followed the angular io website only while updating . So all the steps mentioned there have been strictly followed . Not sure what's wrong .

Comment: npm i already done? :)

Comment: @Janos Vinceller yes